# Us GS to create new doc using .makeCopy

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been following a beginners guide to auto fill a Google doc from a Google form submission and one of the lines of code is supposed to be var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ', ' + firstName, templateResponseFolder); which will make a copy of the doc with the new information however when I type .m there's no drop down or auto completion with anything that is makeCopy. Is there a new script that I'm unaware of? Below is my full script.

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
 var timestamp = e.values[0];
 var firstName = e.values[1];
 var lastName = e.values[2];
 var title = e.values[3];

 var templateFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("1FbWjGH9phpWN2i4vGqWnvJyBG3HPc_uxkHfWsHzg00E");
 var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rEGYnVhJ2vpG_AnqqrVFxPx5rWOmOUj9");

 var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ', ' + firstName, templateResponseFolder);

 var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

 var body = doc.getBody();

 body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstname);
 body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastname);
 body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title);

 doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to  [so]. What do you write before `.m`? Does your script file contains something else? What web browswer are you using? Have you already tried using Chrome in incognito mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, it seems that `templateFile` is `DriveApp.getFolderById()`. I think that there is no method of `makeCopy` in Class Folder. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)
- But, from the length of ID in `DriveApp.getFolderById("1FbWjGH9phpWN2i4vGqWnvJyBG3HPc_uxkHfWsHzg00E")`, I thought that you might have wanted `DriveApp.getFileById("1FbWjGH9phpWN2i4vGqWnvJyBG3HPc_uxkHfWsHzg00E")`. In this case, `templateFile.makeCopy()` can be used.
- And also, in your script, `firstName` and `lastName` are declared. But `firstName` and `lastName` of `body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName)` and   `body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName)` are not declared. If you want to use `firstName` and `lastName`, please also modify them.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var title = e.values[3];
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1FbWjGH9phpWN2i4vGqWnvJyBG3HPc_uxkHfWsHzg00E");  // Modified
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rEGYnVhJ2vpG_AnqqrVFxPx5rWOmOUj9");
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName + ', ' + firstName, templateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);  // Modified
  body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName);  // Modified
  body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)
- [getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I spent way too long staring at this that I needed outside eyes.

Comment: @Emily Prior Thank you for your response.